# Is "The Merry-Go-Round of Life" from Howl's Moving Castle a song in the public domain?

Tags: soundtrack, howls-moving-castle

Is **"The Merry-Go-Round of Life"** from  [Howl's Moving Castle](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0347149/) a song in the public domain?

In particular, was it written specifically for the movie, or was it a public-domain waltz that the producer arranged for the movie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The music was composed for the film by Joe Hisaishi (professional name of Mamoru Fujisawa), who was born in 1950. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Hisaishi):

> Another Miyazaki film, Howl's Moving Castle, for which Hisaishi
>   composed the score, was released on November 20, 2004 in Japan.

Here he is [performing](http://vimeo.com/26381426) it himself. Very moving.

Comment: That video is amazing :D

Comment: Here is a video link that works: https://vimeo.com/19760198